# Problem with formattiing date in Web App that working in Docker

Tags: linux, docker, debian

i have problem with displaying date in my Web Apps.
I want display data in my Web App in format YYYY-MM-DD, but my Web Apps displayes it in format MM/DD/YYYY.
The WebApps is in Docker container and here is ok:
[image]

The Docker Service is working in Debian system, and here is ok, again:"

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSbf1.png]

I don't understand, why my app is show me it:

[image]

I use ASP.NET Core and I got the image from here:
https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet

Kind Regards,
Lukasz